# What is your estimation for a fair market value for a share of the REIT

Tags: real-estate

From the question below am having some issues in solving it. I know that  Fair Market Value of Assets = Net asset value+Liabilities. However, in this case am dealing with stocks and I need to find the market value for a share. How do I move from what I know to stocks or is it a new concept all together?

Consider a REIT that holds high quality office building in some of the best locations in the U.S. The REIT is currently traded at a price of $65/Share and there are 110 million shares outstanding.

Expected next year total revenue:$680M

Expected next year total expenses (including interest and depreciation):$350M

Expected next year depreciation:$80M

Expected next year interest: $60M

Total Debt: $2.0B

Current Office CAP in the U.S.: 4.5% to 6.0% depending on quality and location.

a. What is your estimation for a fair market value for a share of the REIT described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with the concept of 'cap rates' in US commercial real estate? The Cap Rate is a number such that the Market Value of the building is equal to the NOI (net operating income) divided by the cap rate. Estimates of cap rates for various kinds of buildings are publicly available (and included in the problem statement here).

Start by computing the NOI (which is income before depreciation and interest) from the figures given above and divide it by 0.045 (high quality cap rate of 4.5%) to get the building MV. You know the REIT Debt is 2 billion so find the value of the REIT equity by subtraction. Debt+Equity = MV . Finally divide the Equity by the number of shares to find the price per share.

Comment: I highly appreciate Alex. I have calculated and got a value of $76.76. Something am not quite sure I got correctly is the NOI. Am wondering, if I should take the expected revenue and subtract expenses without including depreciation and interest. i.e 680-(350-80-60) =470M. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Indeed that is what I meant. Good luck to you.